# How to extend FOSRestBundle RequestBodyParamConverter?

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am new to Symfony (5.3) and would like to extend the `RequestBodyParamConverter` (FOSRestBundle 3.0.5) to create a REST api. Using `@ParamConverter` annotation with the `RequestBodyParamConverter` works fine. However, I would like to create a custom converter, which does the exact same job as `RequestBodyParamConverter` plus a little extra work.

My first guess was to simply extend `RequestBodyParamConverter` and provide my custom subclass in the `@ParamConverter` annotation. However, `RequestBodyParamConverter` is defined as `final` and thus cannot be extended...

Injecting `RequestBodyParamConverter` / `fos_rest.request_body_converter` into a custom converter class (see example below) also fails because the service cannot be found. I assume this is because it is defined a `private`?

So, my last idea was to create a `RequestBodyParamConverter` inside my custom converter class. While this works, I am not sure if this is the *right* way to solve this problem. This way `RequestBodyParamConverter` is created twice. This is nothing special of course, but is this the *Symfony way* to solve this or are there other solutions?

**Example:**

Inject `RequestBodyParamConverter` in custom converter class

```
class MyParamConverter implements ParamConverterInterface {
    protected $parentConverter;
    public function __construct(ParamConverterInterface $parentConverter) {
        $this->parentConverter = $parentConverter;
    }

    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration): bool {
        doExtraWork();
        return $this->parentConverter->apply(...);
    }
}

// config/services.yaml
My\Project\MyParamConverter:
    tags:
        - { name: request.param_converter, converter: my_converter.request_body }
    arguments:
        # both fails since service is not found
        $parentConverter: '@FOS\RestBundle\Request\RequestBodyParamConverter'

        # OR

        $parentConverter: '@fos_rest.request_body_converter'
```

Create `RequestBodyParamConverter` in custom converter class

```
class MyParamConverter implements ParamConverterInterface {
    protected $parentConverter;
    public function __construct(...parameters necessary to create converter...) {
        $this->parentConverter = new RequestBodyParamConverter(...);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony provide a way to [decorate a registered service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html)

To use it you need the FOS service id registered in the container.

To get it you can use this command

```
symfony console debug:container --tag=request.param_converter
```

Retrieve the `Service ID` of the service you want to override.

Then you can configure your service to decorate FOS one

```
My\Project\MyParamConverter:
    decorates: 'TheIdOf_FOS_ParamConverterService'
    arguments: [ '@My\Project\MyParamConverter.inner' ] # <-- this is the instance of fos service
```

Maybe you'll need to add the `tags` to this declaration, I'm not sure.

Let me know if you're facing an error.